# How to embed a flash movie in a facebook canvas

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flash, facebook

I am trying to embed a flash movie into a facebook (iframe) canvas.  When i request the page locally to test the movie is embedded.  When I view the same page via the facebook application url - the movie doesn't appear (but other page content does).

Here is the jquery code I'm using to load the video:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("6.0.0")) {
        var fn = function () {
            var att = { data: "flash/video.swf", width: "385", height: "312" };
            var par = { flashvars: "foo=bar" };
            var id = "video-container";
            swfobject.createSWF(att, par, id);
        };
        swfobject.addDomLoadEvent(fn);
    }


 });
```

and here is the html:

```
<div id="video-container">
</div>
<div>where o where can my video be?</div>
```

Are there any special tricks required to make a flash movie play in a facebook canvas application?

Comment: just a little javascript nitpicking here.. you could combine all those separate var statements inside the 'fn' function into one comma separated var declaration. also, you don't need to define myObject as you are declaring it locally and not using it for anything else.

Comment: thanks.  I will clean it up and edit the question.    Didn't combine the var statements - left them for readability for other visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making the link to the flash file absolute:

eg `http://www.yoursite.com/flash/video.swf`

Comment: good to hear, its pretty easy to get flash on facebook now.. before you'd have to do some awesome click to activate stuff or use fb:swf which was a paaaaain